# File not Found exception when file is actually a resource

Tags: c#, file, resources, filenotfoundexception

Friends will you please check this code out and tell me why do I get a `FileNotFoundException` and `PathIsIllegal` Exceptions...??

```
    void AddSearchTermLog(String term)
        {
            String data = File.ReadAllText(global::BenisImageDownloader.Properties.Resources.SearchTerms);
            if (data != String.Empty)
            {
                String temp = String.Empty;
                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (data[i] == (char)Keys.Enter)
                    {
                        if (temp == term)
                            return;
                        temp = String.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                        temp += data[i];
                }
            }
            File.AppendAllText(global::BenisImageDownloader.Properties.Resources.SearchTerms, term + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

If I'm doing something wrong, please do correct me with the right method..

Answer (score 1):

[`File.ReadAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) method takes a `string` as a parameter which you tried to open, read and close the file. Check it out from MSDN.

I don't think so `global::BenisImageDownloader.Properties.Resources.SearchTerms` is a `string`.

Comment: But it is a file as a resource, then how to manipulate add and delete from it..?? Is there an another way..???

Comment: I don't know but If you use `ReadAllText()` you should use string parameter for `path`.

Comment: But this thing is not returning any syntax or inappropriate implicit type conversion error, also if we use image files instead of text files from the resource for a PictureBox control or an Image object, it works fine.. Then why not with a simple ReadAllText() Method...??  If you see it from my side, its a genuine question...